# Java jsf beans - Nullpointer exception

Tags: java, jsf, persistence, javabeans

For school I'm making this website which is a look-a-like of twitter. Now I have this nullpointer exception for over 2 days now. I would like some help on the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   javassist.util.proxy.RuntimeSupport$DefaultMethodHandler.invoke(RuntimeSupport.java:37)
>     at
>   org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_587.findAll(Object_$$_javassist_587.java)
>     at
>   bean.KwetterBean.Followers(KwetterBean.java:218)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:304)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:298)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ClientProxyMethodHandler.java:113)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.CleanableMethodHandler.invoke(CleanableMethodHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   bean.KwetterBean_$$_javassist_593.Followers(KwetterBean_$$_javassist_593.java)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:737)
>     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:467)
>     at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:246)
>     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:111)
>     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
>     at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:71)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:217)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:78)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:176)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:273)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Now the classes involved:

KwetterBean.java

> /*  * To change this template, choose
>   Tools | Templates  * and open the
>   template in the editor.  */ package
>   bean;
>
> import domain.*; import
>   java.io.Serializable; import
>   java.util.ArrayList; import
>   java.util.Collection; import
>   java.util.Collections; import
>   java.util.Comparator; import
>   java.util.Date; import
>   java.util.HashMap; import
>   java.util.Iterator; import
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap; import
>   java.util.LinkedList; import
>   java.util.List; import java.util.Map;
>   import javax.ejb.EJB; import
>   javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
>   import javax.inject.Named;
>
> import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
>
> import
>   javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
>   import
>   javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
>   import javax.inject.Inject;
>
> import service.IUserService;
>
> /**  *  * @author Julian  */ @Named
>   @ManagedBean @SessionScoped public
>   class KwetterBean implements
>   Serializable {
>
> ```
> // DATA
> @Inject    private IUserService uService;
> private User user;
> private String newTweet;
> private int newTweetLength;
> private String twitterFilter;
> private String trend = "";
>
> // PROPERTIES
> public int getnewTweetLength() {
>     return newTweetLength;
> }
>
> public User getUser() {
>     if (user == null) {
>         //user = new User("test", "test", "test");
>         user = uService.find(0);
>     }
>     return user;
> }
>
> public String getNewTweet() {
>     return newTweet;
> }
>
> public void setNewTweet(String newTweet) {
>     this.newTweet = newTweet;
> }
>
> public void LimitTweetLength(AjaxBehaviorEvent
> ```
>
> event) {
>           newTweetLength = newTweet.length();
>       }
>
> ```
> public String getTwitterFilter() {
>     return twitterFilter;
> }
>
> public void setTwitterFilter(String twitterFilter)
> ```
>
> {
>           this.twitterFilter = twitterFilter;
>       }
>
> ```
> public Collection<Tweet> getMentioned() {
>     List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
>     for (User u : uService.findAll()) {
>         for (Tweet t : u.getTweets()) {
>             String[] words = t.getTweet().split(" ");
>             for (String word : words) {
>                 if (word.equals("@" + user.getName())) {
>                     tweets.add(t);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     // Custom comparator
>     Collections.sort(tweets, new Comparator() {
>
>         @Override
>         public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
>             Tweet p1 = (Tweet) o1;
>             Tweet p2 = (Tweet) o2;
>             return p2.getDatum().compareTo(p1.getDatum());
>         }
>     });
>     return tweets;
> }
>
> public void setTrend(String trend)
> {
>     this.trend = trend;
> }
>
> public Collection<Tweet> getTrendTimeLine() {
>     List<Tweet> trendTweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
>     for (User u : uService.findAll()) {
>         for (Tweet t : u.getTweets()) {
>             String[] words = t.getTweet().split(" ");
>             for (String word : words) {
>                 if(word.equals(trend))
>                     trendTweets.add(t);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     // Custom comparator
>     Collections.sort(trendTweets, new Comparator() {
>
>         @Override
>         public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
>             Tweet p1 = (Tweet) o1;
>             Tweet p2 = (Tweet) o2;
>             return p2.getDatum().compareTo(p1.getDatum());
>         }
>     });
>     return trendTweets;
> }
>
> public List<String> getTrends() {
>     List<String> templist = new ArrayList<String>();
>     HashMap<String, Integer> trends = new HashMap<String,
> ```
>
> Integer>();
>           for (User u : uService.findAll()) {
>               for (Tweet t : u.getTweets()) {
>                   String[] words = t.getTweet().split(" ");
>                   for (String word : words) {
>                       if (word.startsWith("#")) {
>                           if (trends.containsKey(word)) {
>                               trends.put(word, trends.get(word) +
>   1);
>                           } else {
>                               trends.put(word, 1);
>                           }
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>           trends = (HashMap) sortByValue(trends);
>           Iterator testiter = trends.keySet().iterator();
>           while (testiter.hasNext()) {
>               templist.add((String) testiter.next());
>           }
>           if(templist.size() < 5)
>               return templist;
>
> ```
>     return templist.subList(0, 5);
> }
>
> public Collection<Tweet> getTimelineTweets() {
>     if(!trend.isEmpty())
>         return getTrendTimeLine();
>     List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
>     tweets.addAll(user.getTweets());
>     for (User following : user.getFollowing()) {
>         tweets.addAll(following.getTweets());
>     }
>
>     if (twitterFilter != null && twitterFilter.length() > 0) {
>         Collection<Tweet> filteredTweets = new
> ```
>
> ArrayList();
>               for (Tweet t : tweets) {
>                   if (t.getTweet().indexOf(twitterFilter) >
>   -1) {
>                       filteredTweets.add(t);
>                   }
>               }
>               return filteredTweets;
>           }
>           // Custom comparator
>           Collections.sort(tweets, new Comparator() {
>
> ```
>         @Override
>         public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
>             Tweet p1 = (Tweet) o1;
>             Tweet p2 = (Tweet) o2;
>             return p2.getDatum().compareTo(p1.getDatum());
>         }
>     });
>     return tweets;
> }
>
> // METHODS
> public void setUser(String name) {
>     List<User> temp = uService.findAll();
>     for (User u : temp) {
>         if (u.getName().equals(name)) {
>             this.user = u;
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> public void submitTweet() {
>     if (newTweet != null && newTweet.length() > 0) {
>         Tweet tweet = new Tweet(newTweet, new Date(), "PC");
>         user.addTweet(newTweet);
>         newTweet = "";
>         newTweetLength = 0;
>     }
> }
>
> public Collection<User> Followers(User user) {
>     List<User> tempUserList = new ArrayList<User>();
>     Iterator<User> iterator = uService.findAll().iterator();
>     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
>         User tempUser = iterator.next();
>         if (tempUser.getFollowing().contains(user))
> ```
>
> {
>                   tempUserList.add(tempUser);
>               }
>           }
>           return tempUserList;
>       }
>
> ```
> public String viewUser(User user) {
>     trend = "";
>     this.user = user;
>     return "index.xhtml";
> }
>
> public List<String> getAllUsers() {
>     List<String> tempUserList = new ArrayList<String>();
>     Iterator<User> iterator = uService.findAll().iterator();
>     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
>         tempUserList.add(iterator.next().getName());
>     }
>     return tempUserList;
> }
>
> public String Login() {
>     return "login.xhtml";
> }
>
> public String Logout() {
>     return "index.xhtml";
> }
>
> private static Map sortByValue(Map map) {
>     List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
>     Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
>
>         @Override
>         public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
>             return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry)
> ```
>
> (o2)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry)
>   (o1)).getValue());
>               }
>           });
>
> ```
>     Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
>     for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
>         Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
>         result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
>     }
>     return result;
> } }
> ```

UserServiceJPA.java

> > /*  * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates  * and open
> >     the template in the editor.  */
>
> package service;
>
> import domain.User; import
>   java.util.ArrayList; import
>   java.util.List; import
>   javax.ejb.Stateful; import
>   javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
>   import
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager;
>   import
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
>   import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
>
> /**  *  * @author Julian  */ @Stateful
>   @Alternative public class
>   UserServiceJPA implements IUserService
>   {
>
> ```
> @PersistenceContext(unitName="Kwetter")
> private EntityManager em;
>
> @Override
> public int count() {
>     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not
> ```
>
> supported yet.");
>       }
>
> ```
> public UserServiceJPA() {
>
>     initUsers();
> }
>
> public void initUsers(){
>     User u1 = new User("Hans","http","geboren 1");
>     User u2 = new User("Frank","httpF","geboren 2");
>     User u3 = new User("Tom","httpT","geboren 3");
>     User u4 = new User("Sjaak","httpS","geboren 4");
>
>     this.create(u1);
>     this.create(u2);
>     this.create(u3);
>     this.create(u4);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void create(User user) {
>     em.persist(user);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void edit(User user) {
>     User user2 = new User();
>     user2 = em.find(User.class, user.getId());
>     user2.setFollowing(user.getFollowing());
>     user2.setTweets(user.getTweets());
> }
>
> @Override
> public User find(int id) {
>     User user1 = new User();        
>     user1 = em.find(User.class, (long)id);
>     return user1;
> }
>
> @Override
> public List<User> findAll() {
>     List<User> users = new ArrayList();
>
>     TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery("select u From User u",
> ```
>
> User.class);
>           for (User user1 : query.getResultList()) {
>               users.add(user1);
>           }
>
> ```
>     return users;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void remove(User user) {
>     em.remove(user);
> }
> ```
>
> }

In this above class I only use the init once so the users are in the database but it wont create the users in the database, it does make the tables though.

I hope somebody can show me where the error is made because I really have no idea of what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

**New error:**

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.CreationException:
>   WELD-000079 Could not find the EJB in
>   JNDI:  class
>   org.javassist.tmp.java.io.Serializable_$$_javassist_633
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean.create(SessionBean.java:315)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.DependentContext.get(DependentContext.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:709)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:771)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:794)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:108)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:790)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:802)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:177)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:130)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:47)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:171)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:142)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:165)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:332)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractMapContext.get(AbstractMapContext.java:112)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyMethodHandler.getProxiedInstance(ClientProxyMethodHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ClientProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.CleanableMethodHandler.invoke(CleanableMethodHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   bean.KwetterBean_$$_javassist_644.getUser(KwetterBean_$$_javassist_644.java)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
>     at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
>     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
>     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
>     at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:71)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:217)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:78)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:176)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:273)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error
>   resolving session object reference for
>   ejb name class service.UserServiceJPA
>   and jndi name
>   java:global/Kwetter_-_Julian/UserServiceJPA!service.IUserService
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.services.EjbServicesImpl.resolveEjb(EjbServicesImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean.createReference(SessionBean.java:422)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean.create(SessionBean.java:298)
>     ... 68 more Caused by:
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException:
>   Communication exception for
>   SerialContext  [Root exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException]
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:461)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.services.EjbServicesImpl.resolveEjb(EjbServicesImpl.java:110)
>     ... 71 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
>     at $Proxy223.create(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.JavaGlobalJndiNamingObjectProxy.create(JavaGlobalJndiNamingObjectProxy.java:61)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:432)
>     ... 74 more Caused by:
>   javax.ejb.CreateException: ERROR
>   creating stateful SessionBean     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(StatefulSessionContainer.java:553)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(BaseContainer.java:2425)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalHomeImpl.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(EJBLocalHomeImpl.java:113)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalHomeInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalHomeInvocationHandler.java:153)
>     ... 77 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   service.UserServiceJPA.create(UserServiceJPA.java:52)
>     at
>   service.UserServiceJPA.initUsers(UserServiceJPA.java:44)
>     at
>   service.UserServiceJPA.(UserServiceJPA.java:35)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
>     at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer._constructEJBInstance(StatefulSessionContainer.java:569)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1616)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createBeanInstance(StatefulSessionContainer.java:581)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(StatefulSessionContainer.java:534)
>     ... 80 more

Comment: tl;dr, please learn how to debug.

Comment: @BalusC Java is a pain in the ass to debug anyway. Blame sun.

Comment: The information provided by Java stacktraces is one of most extensive in programming languages. Not knowing how to interpret them and being ignorant about debugging techniques is not Sun's fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @EJB instead of @Inject for the service Dependency injection

Comment: Then I get this error: SEVERE: Cannot resolve reference Remote ejb-ref name=bean.KwetterBean/uService,Remote 3.x interface =service.IUserService,ejb-link=null,lookup=null,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session because there are 2 ejbs  in the application with interface service.IUserService
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app

Comment: is the IUserService interface annotated with `@Local` ?  This is used to show that the it is a local EJB not a remote one.

Comment: remove the @Alternative annotation .. in the javadocs of the annotation it says ..  * 
 * <p>An alternative is not available for injection, lookup 
 * or EL resolution to classes or JSP/JSF pages in a module 
 * unless the module is a bean archive and the alternative is 
 * explicitly <em>selected</em> in that bean archive. An 
 * alternative is never available for injection, lookup or EL 
 * resolution in a module that is not a bean archive.</p>

Answer (score 1):

`bean.KwetterBean.Followers(KwetterBean.java:218` seems to be the place you should look at.

Probably `user.getFollowing()` is returning `null` and calling `contains()` on it makes it bomb.

I think you should connect with a debugger, set this to stop on NPE and just see where it stops. This will allow you to inspect the variables and get a fix quicker than waiting for answers here.

Comment: Also if I make sure it wont return a null value it gives the next error which I'll put at the end of my question.

Comment: I think your init Users only populates the users , but does not add any follower information - but then, the formatting of the code above does not really make users spend time to help you, as it is hard to read.

Comment: And you need some method (e.g. from servlet.init() ) calling your initUsers() at all.

Comment: Don't know how to format it in another way? Its just alot of text. Btw if your first sentence is true then it would create the users in the database, but that's the problem. It doesn't.

Comment: @Heiko: The constructor of UserServiceJPA calls it.

Comment: in the constructor, you won't have an open transaction. You should annotate the init method with @PostConstruct which is called automatically when the EJB is initialised completly